# Can other modes be applied in OpenPGP (not using CFB mode)?

Tags: aes, pgp

According to https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880.html#section-13.9
-> OpenPGP only mentioned about CFB mode.

According to https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/projects/cryptographic-module-validation-program/documents/security-policies/140sp3729.pdf
(section 2.1 and 3.10)
-> AES GCM mode is also approved to use

I am going to implement an application follow RFC 4880
My question is: why RFC 4880 only mentioned about CFB mode. Could I use AES GCM mode?

Comment: RFC 4880 is written in 2007 and RFC's are generally not updated in those manners, only errata exist. FIPS 197 SP 800-38D existed in the same year, and don't expect coordination between the groups. See [Work in progress to update the OpenPGP specification from RFC4880](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-ietf-openpgp-rfc4880bis-10.html) the preferred modes are [AEAD-EAX and AEAD-OCB](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-ietf-openpgp-rfc4880bis-10.html#aead-algorithms)